# Do marginals of all linear transformations uniquely characterize a distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, linear-transformations

One can easily find an example of two random variables $X,Y$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that have the same marginals but are not equal. Does this still hold if I strengthen the assumption to assuming that the marginals *of any linear transformation* of $X$ and $Y$ are the same? That is, if I assume that for any linear map $L$, it holds that marginals of $L(X)$ and $L(Y)$ are the same?

Comment: At most, you will get equality of distributions. You won't get $X = Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is called the Cramer-Wold device. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem